# Narrow class number of a the maximal totally real number field inside a cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am wondering how much it is known about the narrow class number of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1})$ ($p$ an odd prime). More precisely, I am interested to know when it is odd.

By computing in MAGMA (assuming GRH) for p=7,11,$\cdots$ 83 I found that it is always $1$ apart from when $p=29$ (when it is 8).

Any help\literature to read would be much appreciated!

Comment: The class number for $p = 29$ is $8$, not $6$.  For a recent article on the unit signatures of cyclotomic fields see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.02185.pdf and https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153298#metadata_info_tab_contents